# Why won't docker start in Ubuntu 18?

Tags: 18.04, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to start my docker service but it keeps failing.

I use the following command to start docker

```
sudo service docker start
```

And then as soon as I hit enter, I get the following output

```
* Starting Docker: docker
```

And then when I check the status of docker I get this message

```
* Docker is not running
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: So you're running Ubuntu 18.04 under WSL2 on Windows 10, correct?

Comment: I don't know if it's "under WSL2", but yes I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10.

Comment: In your post, please include the output of `systemctl status docker`.

Comment: I did. It's  ` * Docker is not running `.

Comment: Please see [this link](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#status%20PATTERN%E2%80%A6%7CPID%E2%80%A6%5D) how a `systemctl status` output is formatted.

Comment: `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.`

Comment: Ok I don't know enough about WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) to be able to offer any more advice - sorry.

Answer (score 1):

To start the Docker daemon on WSL2 you’ll need to use the following command:

```
sudo dockerd
```

A lot of people tend to go with [Docker Desktop](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/) as it drastically simplifies management of Docker on Windows.

Comment: I've tried several times to download Docker Desktop, but it keeps telling me that I need to upgrade my system to Windows Home 10 (18362.1040+). I've tried to upgrade my Windows through Settings but the update keeps failing. I also tried using the Windows Update program but that thing has been stuck at 99% download for the past 2 days.

Comment: Also sudo dockerd didn't work for me.